# useContext not forcing sibling component re-render when context values change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I am in the process of learning React and am working on a project for a course that I am taking. I have created a react app which has numerous functional components and which uses react routing.

What I am trying to accomplish here is to have the NavBar component re-render once a user has completed the login process so that I can then programmatically display different Navbar items based on the current context values.

I am able to see updates to other components when userContext is updated but not with the Navbar. What am I missing/doing wrong?

index.js

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import App from './App';
const UserContext   = React.createContext(null);

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();

export default UserContext;
```

App.js

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import React from 'react';
import {HashRouter, Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom';
import NavBar from './navbar';
import Home from './home';
import CreateAccount from './createaccount';
import Login from './login';
import Deposit from './deposit';
import Withdraw from './withdraw';
import Balance from './balance';
import AllData from './alldata';
import UserContext from './index.js'



export default function App() {

  return(
    <HashRouter>
      <UserContext.Provider value={{users: [{name:'defaultuser', email: 'default@default.com', password: 'DFS)(Uqadfasfda234##', balance: 0, loggedIn: 0}]}}>
      <NavBar/>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/CreateAccount/" element={<CreateAccount />} />
            <Route path="/login/" element={<Login />} />
            <Route path="/deposit/" element={<Deposit />} />
            <Route path="/withdraw/" element={<Withdraw />} />
            <Route path="/balance/" element={<Balance />} />
            <Route path="/alldata/" element={<AllData />} />
          </Routes>
      </UserContext.Provider>
    </HashRouter>
);

}
```

createaccount.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Card from './card.js';
import UserContext from './index.js';
import './styles.css';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';



export default function CreateAccount(){
    const [show, setShow]    = React.useState(true);
    const [status, setStatus]    = React.useState('');
    const [name, setName]    = React.useState('');
    const [balance, setBalance]    = React.useState('');
    const [email, setEmail]    = React.useState('');
    const [password, setPassword]    = React.useState('');
    const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn]    = React.useState(0);
    const ctx = React.useContext(UserContext);
    const navigate = useNavigate();


    function handleClick(){
        navigate("#/login/");
    }

function validate(field, label){
    if (!field) {
        setStatus('Error: ' + label);
        setTimeout(() => setStatus(''), 3000);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function handleCreate(){
    if (!validate(name,     'name'))        return;
    if (!validate(email,    'email'))       return;
    if (!validate(password, 'password'))    return;
    if (!validate(balance, 'balance'))    return;
    ctx.users.push({name,email,password,balance, loggedIn});
    setShow(false);
}


    function clearForm(){
        setName('');
        setEmail('');
        setPassword('');
        setBalance(0.00);
        setShow(true);
    }

    return (
    <div style={{display: "flex", alignItems:"center", justifyContent:"center"}}>
    <Card
        bgcolor="primary"
        header="Create Account"
        status={status}
        body={show ? (
            <>
            Name<br/>
            <input type="input" className="form-control" id="name" placeholder = "Enter name" value={name} onChange={e => setName(e.currentTarget.value)} /><br/>
            Email address<br/>
            <input type= "input" className="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" value={email} onChange={e => setEmail(e.currentTarget.value)} /><br/>
            Password<br/>
            <input type= "password" className ="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Enter password" value={password} onChange={e => setPassword(e.currentTarget.value)} /><br/>
            Starting Balance<br/>
            <input type="input" className="form-control" id="startingbalance" placeholder = "Enter starting balance" value={balance} onChange={e => setBalance(e.currentTarget.value)} /><br/>
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-light" onClick={handleCreate}>Create Account</button>
             
            </>
            ):(
                <>
                <h5>Success</h5>
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-light" onClick={clearForm}>Add another account</button>
                <div className="divider"/>
                <a href="#/login/"><button type="submit" className="btn btn-light" onClick={handleClick}>Login</button></a>
                </>
            )}
            
    />
    </div>

    
)

}
```

login.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Card from './card.js';
import UserContext from './index.js';
import DynamicTable from "./DynamicTable";

let startingBalance = 0.00;


export default function Login(){
    const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn]           = React.useState(0);
    const [userName, setUserName]           = React.useState('');
    const [userPassword, setUserPassword]   = React.useState('');
    const [loggedinUser, setLoggedInUser]   = React.useState(null);
    const [user, setUser]                 = React.useState();
    const [users, setUsers]                 = React.useState([]);
    
    const ctx                               = React.useContext(UserContext);

    function handleLogin(){
        const activeLogin = ctx.users.findIndex(x => x.loggedIn === 1)
        if (activeLogin === -1){
            console.log('Login.js - no active login');
        }
        else {
            if (window.confirm("There is already a logged in user session. Do you wish to log in as a different user?")) {
                alert("The logged in user has changed.");
                logOut();
              } else {
                    return;
              } 
        }
        findUser(userName, userPassword);
    }

    function logOut(){
        let updatedValue = [...ctx.users];
        updatedValue.forEach(element => element.loggedIn = 0);
        setUsers(updatedValue);

    }
    function handleUpdate(i){
        let updatedValue = [...ctx.users];
        updatedValue[i].loggedIn = 1;
        setUsers(updatedValue);
    }

    function findUser(userName){
        setUsers(ctx.users);
        const foundidx = ctx.users.findIndex(x => x.email === userName);
        const found = ctx.users[foundidx];
        let userFirstName = null;
        
        if (!found)
        {
            alert('No user found which matches the email entered. Please try again.');
        }
        else {
            validatePassword(found.password, userPassword, foundidx);
            userFirstName = found.name;
            setUser(userFirstName);
            handleUpdate(foundidx);
            
            startingBalance = parseFloat(found.balance).toFixed(2);

            found.balance = startingBalance;
            
            ctx.users[foundidx].balance = startingBalance;
        }
        
    }

    function validatePassword(password, userPassword, foundidx){

        if (password === userPassword)
        {
            setLoggedIn(1);
            setLoggedInUser(foundidx);
        }
        else {
            alert('You have entered an incorrect password. Repeated failed attempts will result in an account lockout.');
        }
        
    }

    return (
        <div>
        <Card
            bgcolor="warning"
            header={!loggedIn ? (
                "Login"
            ):(
                "Welcome Back " + user + "!"
            )}
            txtcolor="black"
            body={!loggedIn ? (
                <>
                Email<br/>
                <input type= "input" className="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" value={userName} onChange={e => setUserName(e.currentTarget.value)} /><br/>
                Password<br/>
                <input type= "password" className ="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Enter password" value={userPassword} onChange={e => setUserPassword(e.currentTarget.value)} /><br/>
                 <button type="submit" className="btn btn-light" onClick={handleLogin}>Login</button>
                </>
                 ):(
                    <>
                    <h6><b>Current balance:</b> ${startingBalance}</h6>
                    <h6>What would you like to do?</h6>
                    <a className="nav-link" href="#/deposit/">Make Deposit</a>
                    <a className="nav-link" href="#/withdraw/">Make Withdrawal</a>
                    </>
                )}

                
        />
        <DynamicTable />
        </div>
    )
}
```

navbar.js

```
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import React from 'react';
import { OverlayTrigger, Tooltip} from 'react-bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import UserContext from './index.js';



export default function NavBar(){
    const ctx = React.useContext(UserContext);
    const activeLogin = ctx.users.findIndex(x => x.loggedIn === 1);

    if (activeLogin >=0){
        console.log('Navbar.js - there is a logged in user');
    }
    else {
        console.log('Navbar.js - there is NOT a logged in user');
    }

    return (
        
    
    
        <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" bg="dark" variant="dark">
                <OverlayTrigger placement={'right'} overlay={<Tooltip>Show the Home Page</Tooltip>}>
                <Navbar.Brand href="/#">FNBRB</Navbar.Brand>
                </OverlayTrigger>
                <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="respsonive-navbar-nav" />
                    <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
                        <Nav className="me-auto">
                        <OverlayTrigger placement={'right'} overlay={<Tooltip>Create a new account</Tooltip>}>
                            <Nav.Link href="#/CreateAccount/">Create Account</Nav.Link>
                        </OverlayTrigger>
                        
                        <OverlayTrigger placement={'right'} overlay={<Tooltip>Log into an account</Tooltip>}>
                            <Nav.Link href="#/login/">Log In</Nav.Link>
                        </OverlayTrigger>
                        
                        <OverlayTrigger placement={'right'} overlay={<Tooltip>Deposit funds</Tooltip>}>
                            <Nav.Link href="#/deposit/">Deposit</Nav.Link>
                        </OverlayTrigger>                            
                        <OverlayTrigger placement={'right'} overlay={<Tooltip>Withdraw funds</Tooltip>}>
                            <Nav.Link href="#/withdraw/">Withdraw</Nav.Link>
                        </OverlayTrigger>
                        <OverlayTrigger placement={'right'} overlay={<Tooltip>Show all user accounts</Tooltip>}>
                            <Nav.Link href="#/alldata/">All Data</Nav.Link>
                        </OverlayTrigger>
                        </Nav>
                    </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
    
    );
}
```

DynamicTable.js

```
import React from 'react';
import UserContext from './index.js';



  function myFunction(item, index, arr){
    arr[index]['key'] = index;
  }
function DynamicTable(){
// get table column
 
 const ctx = React.useContext(UserContext);
 const userData = ctx.users;
userData.forEach(myFunction);

 const column = Object.keys(userData[0]);
 // get table heading data
 const ThData =()=>{
    
     return column.map((data)=>{
         return <th key={data}>{data}</th>
     })
 }
// get table row data
const tdData =() =>{
   
     return userData.map((data)=>{
       return(
           <tr>
                {
                   column.map((v)=>{
                       return <td>{data[v]}</td>
                   })
                }
           </tr>
       )
     })
}
  return (
      <table className="table">
        <thead>
         <tr>{ThData()}</tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {tdData()}
        </tbody>
       </table>

)
}
export default DynamicTable;
```

card.js

```
import React from 'react';


function Card(props){
    function classes(){
        const bg = props.bgcolor ? ' bg-' + props.bgcolor : ' ';
        const txt = props.txtcolor ? ' text-' + props.txtcolor: ' text-white';
        return 'card mb-3' + bg + txt;
    }

    return(
        <div className={classes()} style={{maxWidth: "18rem"}}>
            <div className="card-header">{props.header}</div>
            <div className="card-body">
                {props.title && (<h5 className="card-title">{props.title}</h5>)}
                {props.text && (<p className="card-text">{props.text}</p>)}
                {props.body}
                {props.status && (<div id='createStatus'>{props.status}</div>)}
            </div>
        </div>
);
}

export default Card;
```

Comment: Immediately after logging in, and the login is successful, what *exactly* are you doing? Is the user automatically redirected anywhere, or are you clicking one of the nav links to go to another page?

Comment: The user is not redirected anywhere. The login page displays the current balance and links to the deposit/withdrawal components. Those additional components are functioning as expected (allow deposit, withdrawal, update balance via useState). 

What I would like to see happen is that upon login the Navbar component be re-rendered so that I can leverage the loggedin value within the UserContext to do other things. For example, conditionally update the NavBar to show "Log Out" instead of "Log In".

Comment: Updating state in the `UserContext.Provider`, e.g. the context value it is providing, will trigger a component rerender. Your code doesn't appear to actually be updating anything though. The `App` component should have some state that you want to enqueue updates for so when it is updated the `UserContext.Provider` sub-ReactTree is rerendered and can access the context value.

Comment: The update is taking place in handleUpdate within login.js. Once that function fires, my context object is updated and the changes can be seen in the dynamic table which shows the data from the context object. 

For example, for now I am showing my dynamic table beneath the <Card> component for the login route. Once a user enters a valid username/password and clicks the Login button, the table beneath the card updates to reflect that the logged in value for the user that logged in has updated from 0 to 1. In addition, the <Card> component re-renders showing some updated info.

Comment: The login component is updating its own state, not anything in the context. I see that `ctx.users` in the context is being mutated, i.e. `ctx.users[foundidx].balance = startingBalance;` is a mutation. We don't mutate objects in React. State and/or props need to be correctly updated in order to trigger a component rerender with the latest state/props values.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

#### Don't mutate state...or anything else

Your components do not re-render because you haven't actually *changed* the value of the context.  That is, the context value is still a reference to the same object.

What you've done is *mutate* the value of the context with this line:

```
ctx.users.push({ name, email, password, balance, loggedIn });
```

`ctx` is still the same object and `ctx.users` is still the same array but the contents have changed.  This sort of change will not trigger React to re-render.  In order to change the value of your context, you must replace the entire object with a new object.

---

You need to:

1. Store the value of the context in a `useState` hook in the `App`.
2. Provide some way for the inner components to call `setState`.

Something along these lines:

```
export default function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([{name:'defaultuser', email: 'default@default.com', password: 'DFS)(Uqadfasfda234##', balance: 0, loggedIn: 0}]});

  // Note: could memoize with useCallback.
  const addUser = (user) => setUsers(prevUsers => prevUsers.concat(user));

  return(
    <HashRouter>
      <UserContext.Provider value={{ users, addUser }}>
      <NavBar/>
```

Comment: Thank you, I am going to go through and refactor to try to address this.